# Capture values of HTML elements in a dynamic table

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, html-table

I have the following dynamic table generated from database.

```html
<form method="post">
    <?php
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($tableQueryExecute)){

        $shift1Oa = $result['operator1'];
        $shift2Oa = $result['operator2'];
        $shift3Oa = $result['operator3'];
        $shift4Oa = $result['operator4'];
        $id = $result['srNumber'];

        echo '<td scope="row">'.$id.'</td>
              <td>                         
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift1PinCount" name="shift1PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 1" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift1Oa" name="shift1Oa" value="'.$shift1Oa.'" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift2PinCount" name="shift2PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 2" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift2Oa" name="shift2Oa" value="'.$shift2Oa.'" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift3PinCount" name="shift3PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 3" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift3Oa" name="shift3Oa" value="'.$shift3Oa.'" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift4PinCount" name="shift4PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 4" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift4Oa" name="shift4Oa" value="'.$shift4Oa.'" disabled>
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="shiftDate" name="shiftDate" value="'.date("Y-m-d").'"></td>

              <td>
                <a href="supervisorEdit.php?source='.$id.'" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savePcData" id="savePcData" value="savePcData">Save</a>
              </td>';

    }

</form>
```

**What I need**

Lets say user clicked `Save` button of a particular row of that table, I want the respective values of that row to be saved in database using `php` `$_POST` or `$_GET` method something like the following

```html
if(isset($_GET['source'])){
    $sourceId = $_GET['source'];
}
```

**Issue**

My issue is, I don't know how to get the `$_POST` values of the form since name of every items are dynamically generating. I tried to make the name unique to each element by adding the unique `$id` value to it as per the following.

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift1Oa" name="shift1Oa'.$id.'" value="'.$shift1Oa.'" disabled>`

I can't capture this unique name values by the following method. Does anyone know why?

```html
if(isset($_GET['source'])){
    $sourceId = $_GET['source'];
    echo $_GET['shift1Oa'.$sourceId];
}
```

**Edit 1**

To get a better picture, following is the screenshot of a row with the button

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct Me If I am not wrong.. Here you want to get the all value from a form Right?  on click of button submit? 
Why you are making this button href?
Suppose we have 3 data into my $result and loops look like below

```
 <form method="post" action="">
<tr>
       <td scope="row"></td>
       <input type ="text" name="sourece" value=1 />
              <td>                         
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift1PinCount" name="shift1PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 1" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift1Oa" name="shift1Oa" value="1" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift2PinCount" name="shift2PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 2" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift2Oa" name="shift2Oa" value="2" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift3PinCount" name="shift3PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 3" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift3Oa" name="shift3Oa" value="3" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift4PinCount" name="shift4PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 4" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift4Oa" name="shift4Oa" value="4" disabled>
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="shiftDate" name="shiftDate" value="<?=date("Y-m-d")?>"></td>

              <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savePcData" id="savePcData" value="savePcData">
              </td> 
</form>
</tr>
<form method="post" action="">
<tr>
       <td scope="row"></td>
       <input type ="text" name="sourece" value=2 />
              <td>                         
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift1PinCount" name="shift1PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 1" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift1Oa" name="shift1Oa" value="11" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift2PinCount" name="shift2PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 2" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift2Oa" name="shift2Oa" value="22" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift3PinCount" name="shift3PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 3" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift3Oa" name="shift3Oa" value="33" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift4PinCount" name="shift4PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 4" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift4Oa" name="shift4Oa" value="44" disabled>
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="shiftDate" name="shiftDate" value="<?=date("Y-m-d")?>"></td>

              <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savePcData" id="savePcData" value="savePcData">
              </td> 
</form>
</tr>
<form method="post" action="">
<tr>
       <td scope="row"></td>
       <input type ="text" name="sourece" value=3 />
              <td>                         
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift1PinCount" name="shift1PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 1" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift1Oa" name="shift1Oa" value="111" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift2PinCount" name="shift2PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 2" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift2Oa" name="shift2Oa" value="222" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift3PinCount" name="shift3PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 3" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift3Oa" name="shift3Oa" value="333" disabled>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="shift4PinCount" name="shift4PinCount" placeholder="Pin Count" title="Please key in Pin Count for Shift 4" min=0>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="shift4Oa" name="shift4Oa" value="444" disabled>
              </td>

              <td><input class="form-control" type="date" id="shiftDate" name="shiftDate" value="<?=date("Y-m-d")?>"></td>

              <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savePcData" id="savePcData" value="savePcData">
              </td> 
</form>
</tr>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['savePcData'])){

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    die('mms');

}


?>
```

Your Out put will be 
[image]

here **sourece** is your unique Id which helps you to update the data into your DB

After submitting the form from any tr(row) you will redirect to same page with POST method and get data for that particular row on that page so you can easily update it as you want

You can check this by using print_r($_POST); on same page

If you have any questions please feel free to ask me...

Comment: That is not what i want. In that table, every row has a save button. And when each button press, only that particular row values should be captured and send to MySQL. That is why I am using $_GET variable to the url and capture the serial number

Comment: Okay, no issue but more question as I saw you are using disable in input So you are not able to modify the data right?

Comment: There are disabled as well as enabled inputs in the same row. So all these fields should be capture in that specific row

Comment: I hope you understand my requirement. Do you know how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why are You not using multiple forms for each tr I have edited my answer please check and tell me its work for you or not?

Comment: I tried your advice by keeping every row into a form with post method. Then I used the following codes to get shift4Oa value

`if(isset($_POST['savePcData'])){
                  echo $_POST['shift4Oa'];
              }`
But it is having the error `Undefined index: shift4Oa`

Comment: Please see the edit. I added a picture of the row for better understanding

Comment: I have tried this at my end it's working as you want So I am pasting my code here please have a look at this

Comment: okay got it. So disabled textbox values can't be read by $_POST method?