# How to know if a button have been clicked in a table row bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I have my table in which I display the data from MySql database with PHP and some MySql request.
And this is what it looks like
[image]

So I would like that when a user clicks on the button "voir groupe" it displays some data concerning the subject(matieres) of the same table row with the button in a bootstrap modal .
For example for the 1st row : 
If I click on the button "voir groupe" of the 1st row it displays data in a modal concerning "Architecture"
If I click on the button "voir groupe" of the 4th row it displays data in a modal concerning "Base de données"

So here is my code of my table

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Begin table-->
 <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr class="text">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Matières</th>
            <th>Tuteurs</th>
            <th>Voir groupe</th>
            <th>Avis</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <form method="post" action="avis.php">
          <?php
            $requete = $bdd->query(' SELECT m.intitule_matiere as matiere,e.nom_etudiant as nomtuteur,e.prenom_etudiant as prenomtuteur FROM groupe g INNER JOIN etudiant e ON g.id_etudiant_tuteur=e.id_etudiant INNER JOIN matiere m ON m.id_matiere = g.id_matiere ORDER BY matiere');
            $reqgroupe=$bdd->query('SELECT e.nom_etudiant FROM recoit_soutien as r inner join etudiant as e on r.id_etudiant=e.id_etudiant where r.id_groupe=2');

            $i=1;
              while($data = $requete->fetch()){
                echo'<tr>'
                    .'<td>'.$i.'</td>'
                    .'<td>'.$data['matiere'].'</td>'
                    .'<td>'.$data['nomtuteur'].' '.$data['prenomtuteur'].'</td>'
                    .'<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Voir groupe</button></td>'//  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                    .'<td> <a href="avis.php"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a></td>'
                  .'</tr>';
                  $i++;
               }    
          ?>
          </form>
      </tbody>
      </table> 
 <!--End table-->
```

And here is the code of my bootstrap modal

```html
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Liste des etudiants</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr class="text">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Noms</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            $reqgroupe=$bdd->query('SELECT e.nom_etudiant as nom FROM recoit_soutien as r inner join etudiant as e on r.id_etudiant=e.id_etudiant where r.id_groupe=2');
            $i=1;
              while($data = $reqgroupe->fetch()){
                echo'<tr>'
                    .'<td>'.$i.'</td>'
                    .'<td>'.$data['nom'].'</td>'
                  .'</tr>';
                  $i++;
               }    
          ?>
          </tbody>
      </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try this link for some insight. You could use `$_GET` variable to track which item you clicked and then query that data based on the unique # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463639/capture-values-of-html-elements-in-a-dynamic-table

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you should listen to the event click of a button in all rows by naming class like this `class='btnClick'` then listen to event by `$('.btnClick').click(function()`

**Secondly**, You should find exactly the row by `$(this).closest('tr')`.

**Finally**, You can access any index of a cell by `$row.find('td').eq(0)`

So you can look at my simple example below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a class="btnClick">Click here</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a class="btnClick" >Click here</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>
$(function(){
    $('.btnClick').click(function(){
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $td = $row.find('td').eq(0);
        alert($($td).text());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It may help i think.
But i have to find a way to put the name of the variable in my query Like this : SELECT e.nom_etudiant FROM recoit_soutien as r inner join etudiant as e on r.id_etudiant=e.id_etudiant inner join groupe as g on g.id_groupe=r.id_groupe inner join matiere as m on m.id_matiere=g.id_matiere where m.intitule_matiere like ".$name."

Comment: Obviously, You've got the value $name via the way i give you. It belongs to logical.

Comment: But i don't know how to do it,Could you help me or any links ? i'm stucked

Answer (score 0):

In your table code you have to change like below

```
      <?php
        $requete = $bdd->query(' SELECT m.intitule_matiere as matiere,e.nom_etudiant as nomtuteur,e.prenom_etudiant as prenomtuteur FROM groupe g INNER JOIN etudiant e ON g.id_etudiant_tuteur=e.id_etudiant INNER JOIN matiere m ON m.id_matiere = g.id_matiere ORDER BY matiere');
        $reqgroupe=$bdd->query('SELECT e.nom_etudiant FROM recoit_soutien as r inner join etudiant as e on r.id_etudiant=e.id_etudiant where r.id_groupe=2');

        $i=1;
          while($data = $requete->fetch()){
            echo'<tr>'
                .'<td>'.$i.'</td>'
                .'<td>'.$data['matiere'].'</td>'
                .'<td>'.$data['nomtuteur'].' '.$data['prenomtuteur'].'</td>'
                .'<td><a data-name="<?php echo $data['matiere'];?>" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btnClick"> Voir groupe</a></td>'//  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                .'<td> <a href="avis.php"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i></a></td>'
              .'</tr>';
              $i++;
           }    
      ?>
  </tbody>
```

Secondary you have to how the data on modal by click on button use below code

```
$('.btnClick').on('click',function(){
     var name = $(this).data('name');
//opening model using jquery
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
})
```

And Put that name variable in your table in modal.

Comment: No i have to find a way to put the name in my query Like this :
SELECT e.nom_etudiant FROM recoit_soutien as r 
inner join etudiant as e on r.id_etudiant=e.id_etudiant 
inner join groupe as g on g.id_groupe=r.id_groupe
inner join matiere as m on m.id_matiere=g.id_matiere
where m.intitule_matiere like ".$name."

Comment: Ok then you have to do ajax call on click and pass the `var name` as data in ajax and then after in success you can open your modal using the above code.

Comment: That's i'm **going to do**